# How can I get `defaults write com.apple.screencapture` to change screen capture location in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I used to be able to set the key `location` under `com.apple.screencapture` to change the save location for the system-wide screen capture facility.

This doesn't work for me anymore -- screenshots save to the Desktop regardless of the setting of `location`. Here's what `defaults` says:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.screencapture
{
 location = "/Users/jogloran/Desktop/Screenshots";
}
```

Comment: It was a permissions issue on that folder in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me quite happily.

[image]

Have you restarted UIserver?

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Does the path exist?

UPDATE: If the screen capture cannot find or write to the designated folder, it will default to the current user's desktop.

Comment: +1 for this. As well, have you made sure to include the "location" portion of the command? I forgot to do this myself a couple times and never got any correction from the command line.

Comment: @Veil I'm sure he has, as the output of the defaults read command gives a valid looking path

Comment: I definitely have. The path does exist. I've tried restarting SystemUIServer too -- this persists through reboots.

Comment: @jogloran if screen capture cannot find or write to the folder, then it will default to the Desktop.  Check your file permissions on the folder, triple check the path, and all else fails, run repair permissions.